# Creating new column for unique code for each row on column basis using python

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I was trying to create a query loop, which does interactive steps from one instance to the next. After fetching the right data.

Connected python to SQL server and returned table schema column name and type in a variable.

Here I am trying to create `hashbyte` for every record in the database save a column name as `hk`

I am getting error:

> ProgrammingError: ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name ''COL_NAMES''. (207) (SQLExecDirectW)")

My desired output will be column name as `hk` should be saved in the database and has a unique code for all the row as

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you already have your list of column names ...

```python
>>> COL_NAMES = ['ID', 'NAME', 'Date']  # sample data
```

... and you can insert them into the `lower(isnull(...` fragment with a list comprehension and then join them together with plus signs ...

```python
>>> s = '+'.join([f"lower(isnull(convert(nvarchar(255),[{x}]), ''))" for x in COL_NAMES])
>>> s
"lower(isnull(convert(nvarchar(255),[ID]), ''))+lower(isnull(convert(nvarchar(255),[NAME]), ''))+lower(isnull(convert(nvarchar(255),[Date]), ''))"
```

... and then insert that into the rest of the SQL statement

```python
>>> sql = f"SELECT HASHBYTES('MD5', {s}) as hk, * INTO [dbo].[ABCD_A] FROM [dbo].[ABC_A]"
>>> sql
"SELECT HASHBYTES('MD5', lower(isnull(convert(nvarchar(255),[ID]), ''))+lower(isnull(convert(nvarchar(255),[NAME]), ''))+lower(isnull(convert(nvarchar(255),[Date]), ''))) as hk, * INTO [dbo].[ABCD_A] FROM [dbo].[ABC_A]"
```

Comment: @PURU - Look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498).

Comment: @PURU - That's a different problem so you should [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: hey @Gord Thompson - look into it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57340041/removing-on-the-basis-of-condition help me out  thanks